# Intellij 14 fails to launch after installing JDK9 on MacOS Sierra

Tags: intellij-idea, java-9

After installing JDK9, when I tried starting IntelliJ 14, it shows an error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/Resource
```

I tried launching it via CLI:

```
/Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ 14.app/Contents/MacOS/idea
```

and it showed the error message:

```
/Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ 14.app/Contents/MacOS/idea 
2017-10-06 13:37:14.708 idea[62378:12084995] Value of IDEA_JDK: (null)
2017-10-06 13:37:14.711 idea[62378:12084995] find Java: (null)
2017-10-06 13:37:14.711 idea[62378:12084995] required JavaVersion: 1.6.0_65-b14-466.1
2017-10-06 13:38:10.078 idea[62378:12084995] No matching VM found.
2017-10-06 13:38:10.079 idea[62378:12084995] update Java is required
```

Despite doing an

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7)
```

it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: The support to intelliJ for Java9 was added around 2017.1 and no doubts trying to access 2014 with that would break. https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/07/support-for-java-9-in-intellij-idea-2017-2/

Comment: This is to clarify issues for folks who have trouble launching their IntelliJ 2014 after they've installed JDK9. So, folks are not forced to upgrade to 2017 or later.

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr
I am pretty sure I had it working with JDK-7 earlier but I think the quickest solution is to just download JDK-6 again: https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

---

Also, some additional information:
You can see all your current JDK versions by

```
ls -al /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
```

If you don't have 1.6.0.jdk - that may be the problem, since IntelliJ seems to be looking for it.

Despite attempts to switch the JDK version using the `export` command, it doesn't seem to stick as Mac seems to pick the highest version of those listed above. You can find the versions currently available by running

```
/usr/libexec/java_home
```

Looks like you can disable newer version by going into the `jdk`s in the above path and then rename the `jdk1.X.YY_ZZ.jdk/Contents/Info.plist` to `jdk1.X.YY_ZZ.jdk/Contents/Info.plist.disabled`. However, note that you can't activate those environments, if you do this.